# Problema al imprimir variables en type="number" html desde javascript

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Quiero imprimir mis variables de `JS` en un `<input type="text">` pero no puedo, mas sin embargo puedo hacerlo en un `<span></span>` y en un alert.

Lo que realmente quiero es poderlos enviar a un archivo `PHP` por `POST` para poder guardarlos.

Lo imprimo en `<span id="Subtotal">`

Pero necesito imprimir en un `<input type="text" id="Subtotal">`

```
function totales() {    
       var Precio = document.getElementById("Precio").value;
       var Cantidad = document.getElementById("Cantidad").value;
       var Subtotal = document.getElementById("Subtotal").value;
       var IVA = document.getElementById("IVA").value;
       var Total = 0;

       Subtotal = (Precio * Cantidad);
       document.getElementById('Subtotal').innerHTML = "$" + Subtotal;

       IVA = (Subtotal * 0.16);

       document.getElementById('IVA').innerHTML = "$" + IVA;

       Total = (Subtotal + IVA);
       document.getElementById('Total').innerHTML = "$" + Total;    
}
```

Comment: No termina de quedar clara tu duda,  ¿al no poder hacer lo que dices obtienes algún mensaje de error?, por que después dices algo de guardarlos con PHP pero la pregunta inicial no versa de eso, checa [ask]

Comment: No me genera mensaje de error, en pocas palabras necesito imprimir una variables javascript en un input type="text"

Comment: Bueno es que para colocar un valor en un `input` no se usa `innerHTML` si no `value`, prueba cambiar esto que te digo

Comment: Si no es mucha molestia, me podrias dar un ejemplo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás mezclando un poco las cosas con el título de la pregunta, el input de tipo numérico solo acepta como se indica, números, por lo tanto te dará error al intentar poner un valor de **$20** por ejemplo.

Y para modificar el valor de un input es mediante value:

```
Subtotal = (Precio * Cantidad);
document.getElementById("Subtotal").value = Subtotal;
```

Lo que podrías hacer es algo como:

```
$ <input id="Subtotal" type="number">
```

Para lograr lo que tú quieres realizar o cambiarlo a tipo text.